# Dpkt lib - how to add timestamp to packet

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp

So I am trying to create my own pcap file, I've created a msg using dpkt but I am not understanding how to maneuver timestamp, from what I've seen it is the 3rd parameter in writepkt but I don't understand how to initial the variable.. this is a part of my code

```
output_pcapfile = dpkt.pcap.Writer(open(__file__+'.pcap','wb'))
tcpSrc.data = 'Some data\r\n'
ipSrc.data  = tcpSrc

ipSrc.len   = len(str(ipSrc))
ethSrc.data = ipSrc

packet_count = 1
output_pcapfile.writepkt(ethSrc,packet_count) # somehow get timestamp for third parameter!!
```

Anyone has an idea? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the 1.7 source for `pcap.py`,

I see:

```
 def writepkt(self, pkt, ts=None):
    if ts is None:
        ts = time.time()
    #some more code..
```

This function takes two non-self arguments

The timestamp will be created if you only pass in the `pkt` itself, e.g.

output_pcapfile.writepkt(ethSrc)